# A question regarding a parallel

Tags: past-participles, parallelism, participles, present-participles

I came across a very neat parallel, but I wonder if I can use the structure today without setting off alarm in an editor's head.

> A stretch of a series is any piece *taken out of it, and not having
>   any gaps*.

Source: Whitehead & Russell. *Principia Mathematica*. Merchant Books, 1910.

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly fine to use a past participle and a present participle in parallel like that. You can expand the two participles to full relative clauses: “any piece _which has been taken_ out of it, and _which does not have_ any gaps”. The first clause is passive, the second active; hence the two different participles.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "She likes cooking, jogging, and reading." is OK.  "She likes cooking, jogging, and to read."  will annoy editors.

Comment: Yes, but this is a completely different construction (see my edit).

Comment: Instead of  “and not having any gaps” I'd write “having no gaps”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "cooking and to read", you are conjoining a participle and an infinitive. That's why it does not work.

In "taken and having", you are conjoining a participle and a participle. That's why it works just fine.